# How does Android BroadcastReceiver works at system level?

Tags: android, listener, broadcast

Does a running app need to poll for listening to event broadcast? If not, what is the approach used?

Comment: As you tagged would that be a listener?

Comment: properly name Android object in question and rephrase for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is a 'push' approach used - app register receiver either during installation (if BroadcastReceiver is registered in Manifest), or when app is started.
Then, when broadcat is raised, Android matches IntentFilters for all registered receivers and deliver Intent to that BroadcastReceiver.